# Write a formula to limit usage of special characters?

Tags: regular-expressions

I have a requirement to validate a domain to not include all kind of special characters
The characters I want to limit are:

- `\`
- `/`
- `+`
- `@`

and some more (period is allowed)

I was trying to use REGEX, but can't figure the correct syntax:

`REGEX( Domain__c, "^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])[0-9()/\\-\\+\\s]+$")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
!REGEX(Domain__c,"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$")
```

or

```
REGEX(Domain__c,"^.*[\\\\/\\+\\@]+.*$")
```

The testing result

[image]

Enjoy and have fun.